# How can IBM JWL (Extended HTML JSF Tags by IBM) AJAX examples get to work on WPS 6.1?

Tags: ajax, jsf, websphere-portal

If I try to implement this simple-as-possible example:

[Update Content with AJAXRefreshRequest](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.jsf.doc/topics/rajaxRefreshRequest.html)

it does not work with Websphere Portal 6.1.0.3 on Application Server 6.1.0.27. The content is updated only the first time. In every further request the Bean is not updated from the inputText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no.
I found out that it's working fine with IE 8 in compatibility mode. The AJAX-Components are obviously not compatible to IE 8 (native).

Comment: IBM JSF components are a nightmare. If you can, drop them and use something more decent like RichFaces/Ajax4jsf.